# xCode 3 and SDK iOS 5 (is possible?)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

does anyone knows if i can use xCode 3.2.6 to implement iOS 5 based applications?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no news about the SDK to ios5 but it's possible to create an app in xCode 3.2.6 and upgraded once the new sdk for i0s 5 gets released.

Comment: Apple hasn't announced anything yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install Xcode 4.2 and the iOS5 SDK in a different directory to your existing installtion, when installing choose to install in a different path (for example Developer-new). This way you can keep Xcode 3, but you will still not be able to develop iOS5 apps in it.

(even if it is possible, it is unsupported so you may run into problems later, whether it's technical or Apple just not liking it)

If you're not switching to Xcode 4 because of the new layout, then you really need to, future versions of Xcode will be [highly likely] be based on this, and you will get left behind if you don't make the switch.

Comment: Can anyone verify that after doing this (co-installing an Xcode beta alongside an older version), you can still compile and run code with the old version?

Comment: @Tyler I've has 3 versions at the same time and they've worked as expected. Building chromium in Xcode 3 and developing in Xcode 4 for example.

Answer (score 0):

No, The Xcode and IOS is always in same DMG file. You cannot upgrade IOS without upgrading XCode.
Whether you use XCode 4 with previous versions of IOS.

Comment: Ok, i know this, but for the latest iOS 4.3 SDK you can develop with xcode 4 and 3 too, because there are 2 DMG files.